Why did God allow monetary or shekels of silver as 20% restitution?
Why does God allow monetary restitution (20 shekels of silver) for Sin Offering? I thought that there is no forgiveness without the shedding of the blood.

This would be a much better question if it quoted the relevant scripture that says 20 shekels are required for a sin offering.

From here:

The guilt offering calls for the remorseful sinner to return what was
wrongfully taken plus 20 percent (Lev. 6:4-5). Only after settling the
matter on a human level may the sinner receive forgiveness from God by
presenting an animal to the priest for sacrifice (Lev. 6:6-7).

In other words, this particular offering was a two-part offering, one at a very human, interpersonal level, and one at a personal-and-Divine level. Blood would need to be shed in the second part.

you missed the link, but yes this seems like the most straightforward way to answer.

@GratefulDisciple: Thanks. I just added the link. Don
